# how Can I use spatie/laravel-google-calendar for a web server application with multiple users?

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api

Can I use spatie/laravel-google-calendar for a web server application with multiple users?
anyone please

i want to use this package like user can connect there google account and calendar with app and when they create the event that will show on google calendar

Comment: Show code what have you made so far and ask focused question regarding error you get there. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask good question.